The push address dos not match the remote address I commit to
AS you see the commit is done to the new repo address...but the push is going to another address of existing repo ?
This happing with the last repo 2 days ago till now .
momy@momy:~/IdeaProjects/flutterapp$ git commit -m "version 1.0"
[master 9568edf] version 1.0
1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
momy@momy:~/IdeaProjects/flutterapp$ git remote add origin 
https://github.com/beautybird/Flutter-App-structure.git
error: remote origin already exists.
momy@momy:~/IdeaProjects/flutterapp$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': beautybird
Password for 'https://beautybird@github.com': 
To https://github.com/beautybird/Full-Flutter-app-Parrallex-GoRouter-Supabase.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/beautybird/Full-Flutter-app- 
Parrallex-GoRouter-Supabase.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not
hint: have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to
hint: the same ref. If you want to integrate the remote changes, use
hint: 'git pull' before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
momy@momy:~/IdeaProjects/flutterapp$ 

The terminal Is opened on the intended remote project.
Why is that ?

The message means that the remote branch already has stuff that you do not have locally so it can't accept what you are pushing until you include that stuff into your local branch.

Just in case, about the jargon you are using in the question: a commit is a local operation so no IPs involves there.

my question is why the push try on another remote address . The one I want is git remote add origin
https://github.com/beautybird/Flutter-App-structure.git   BUT the push goes to this on its own https://github.com/beautybird/Full-Flutter-app-
Parrallex-GoRouter-Supabase.git' and abviously  the push fails

I guess you are missing/skipping over this line from that output: error: remote origin already exists.
